# Summarizing JavaScript array based on category and subcategory

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I've been trying to get the summary of the elements in my array. The array contains different values for different categories and i want to summarize the content of the array before the user checks the content of the array.
here is the data:

```
var typed = [
[1, 'MAP: Invalid service'],
[2, 'MAP: map observation'],
[3, 'ADT: Invalid person'],
[4, 'ADT:  verification failed'],
[5, 'SYSTEM: Unrecognized'],
[6, 'SYSTEM: Processing exempt']
[7, 'SYSTEM: Data access'],
[8, 'SYSTEM: Data access'],
[9, 'SYSTEM: Transform Exempt'],
[10, 'SYSTEM: Transform Exempt'],
[11, 'ADT:  verification failed'],
[12, 'ADT: Invalid person']
]
```

I want something of this nature as the summary

```
  4 ADT :
          2 Invalid person
          2 verification failed

 2 MAP: 
          1 Invalid service
          1 map observation

 6 SYSTEM: 
          1 Unrecognized
          1 Processing exempt
          2 Transform exempt
          2 Data access

---------------------
Total: 12
```

Here is what I tried:

```
function summary(typed, category){
    var arrA = [];
    var arrB = [];
    for (var i=0; i<typed.length; i++){
        var tryb = typed[i][4].split(' ');
        for (var j=0; j< category.length; j++){
            if (tryb[0] == category[j]){
            arrA[i][j] = typed[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return arrA;
}
var newcategory = ['ADT:','MAP:'];
summary(typed, newcategory)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lot's of ways to roll through data, split, consolidate and count. Here's one.

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/pLok1h01/)

Given the list you provided (index 6 is missing end comma in your example):

```
var typed = [
[1, 'MAP: Invalid service'],
[2, 'MAP: map observation'],
[3, 'ADT: Invalid person'],
[4, 'ADT:  verification failed'],
[5, 'SYSTEM: Unrecognized'],
[6, 'SYSTEM: Processing exempt'], // added comma
[7, 'SYSTEM: Data access'],
[8, 'SYSTEM: Data access'],
[9, 'SYSTEM: Transform Exempt'],
[10, 'SYSTEM: Transform Exempt'],
[11, 'ADT:  verification failed'],
[12, 'ADT: Invalid person']
]

function summary(typed, category){
    var arrA = {};
    var pass = 0; // pass is used to keep track of type matches below
    for (var i=0; i<typed.length; i++){
        // split on colon and any number spaces gives 2 elements in return
        var tryb = typed[i][1].split(/: +/);
        // if mode does not exist
        if ( !arrA[tryb[0]] ) {
            arrA[tryb[0]] = {};
            arrA[tryb[0]].counter = 1;
            arrA[tryb[0]].types = [];
            arrA[tryb[0]].types.push([1, tryb[1]]);
        }
        // mode does exist
        else {
            arrA[tryb[0]].counter += 1;
            pass = 0;
            // check for existing type
            arrA[tryb[0]].types.forEach(function(val, idx, arr) {
                if ( tryb[1] === val[1] ) {
                    // exists so increment counter
                    arr[idx][0] += 1;
                    pass = 1;
                }
            });
            // newly found type, add to array and count
            if ( !pass ) {
                arrA[tryb[0]].types.push([1, tryb[1]]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrA;
}
// get modes object
var modes = summary(typed);

// this mode object can be reported in many ways,
// a simple text report here
var modes_string = '';
var total = 0;
for ( mode in modes ) {
    modes_string += modes[mode].counter + ' ' + mode + "\n";
    modes[mode].types.forEach(function(val, idx, arr) {
        modes_string += ' ' + modes[mode].types[idx][0] + ' ' + modes[mode].types[idx][1] + "\n";
    });
    modes_string += "\n";
    total += modes[mode].counter;
}
modes_string += 'Total: ' + total;
console.log(modes_string);
```

Outputs:

```
2 MAP
 1 Invalid service
 1 map observation

4 ADT
 2 Invalid person
 2 verification failed

6 SYSTEM
 1 Unrecognized
 1 Processing exempt
 2 Data access
 2 Transform Exempt

Total: 12
```

Comment: Awesome. This did it for me. made a little tweaking and all seems good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your categories are strings, an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is the natural data structure. Since you have two levels of categorization, each outer layer ("ADT", "MAP", etc) should refer to an inner object, where you store the subcategories and how many times they occur; your final structure will look like this:

```
{
  "ADT": {
           "Invalid person": 2,
           "verification failed": 2
         },
  "MAP": {
           "Invalid service": 1,
           "map observation": 1
         }
}
```

You can build this by iterating over the array, splitting the strings in each entry into their relevant components, and updating the appropriate count at each step. Once you have the object, you can pull out the categories and display them however is convenient.

Comment: Couple of things to note here, the different categories are coming from a table which has other columns. This array also has other elements in it but the summary is going to have the count of each of the categories as well as the subcategories. I also have the ADT:, MAP: and the likes in an array because it will certainly be more than these.